# Why i Got Error Dev Express Xamarin forms IOS App Release Issue

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Getting Below error when i try to release app using Linker Behaviour is "Link All" or Link Framework Sdks only"

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Can't resolve the reference 'System.IntPtr ObjCRuntime.DisposableObject::get_Handle()', referenced from the method 'System.String DevExpress.Xamarin.iOS.Charts.DXNumericAxisLabelTextFormatterWrapper::Format(System.Double)' in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'

Answer (score 0):

The Link Framework SDKs Only option will remove some assemblies that are not used by the application and may be removed. You can try selecting the "Don't Link" option, by selecting the "Don't Link" option, you can skip the relevant assembly to avoid the problem. You can refer to the official [documentation of Xamrin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows#skipping-assemblies:%7E:text=by%20type%20name.-,Skipping%20Assemblies,-It%20is%20possible).

Comment: We used Third party Controls like Dev Express controls . if we use "Don't Link" option After release the Build The Appstore sending email like below

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public selectors in inSisMobileApp.iOS: sharedController. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app.